# getting an error Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying set date format as "yyyy/m/d" but getting a Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dateValue As String
Dim technicalName As String

   'If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   technicalName = getTechnicalName(Cells(1, Target.Column).Value)
     If (InStr(technicalName, "{{Date}}") And IsDate(Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Value)) Then

            dateValue = Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Value
            Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Clear
            dateValue = Format(dateValue, "yyyy/m/d")
            Debug.Print dateValue
            Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Value = dateValue

    End If

End Sub
```

Code is getting failed at line :- `Cells(Target.row, Target.Column).Value = dateValue`

Any help would be really appreciated. Funny thing is its working in some systems with same excel version

Comment: Modifying the sheet will cause the event to fire again. A fix is to disable events and then re-enable at the end.

Comment: `Cells(Target.row, Target.Column)` is the same as `Target` (for a single cell)

Comment: "Funny thing is its working in some systems" - your event handler is re-entrant... without that run-time error I'd expect the call stack to blow up and Excel to go down in flames... is this the actual code or some "irrelevant bits" were stripped for the post? FWIW you should treat date values as `Date` and set the appropriate `NumberFormat` on the cell instead of storing dates as strings.